# At what height does water need to fall to produce negative ions?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, atomic-physics, water

Research shows that waterfalls and apparently showers produce negative ions, is there a certain height or velocity for water to fall to produce negative ions?

Comment: This is the first I've heard of it but I have a feeling it is statistical since obviously not all the water that hits splits into into negative ions so asking for a height beyond which it happens might be an inapplicable question.

Comment: I don't know if it answers the question, but it might be worth checking: "Characterization of ions at Alpine waterfalls," 
*Atmos. Chem. Phys.*, **12**, 3687–3697, 2012 (https://www.atmos-chem-phys.net/12/3687/2012/acp-12-3687-2012.pdf)

Comment: Where does the research say the negative ions are produced? Are they possibly referring to a triboelectric effect between the water and air?